# CSS Text Align Not Working With LIs

Tags: html, css

I've got a set of `li`'s containing text which I would like to be displayed and centered horizontally within their `ul` with CSS.  I can't seem to get this to work, another answer suggested using `display:inline` but this did nothing.

Here's the code:

```
header li {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:0px;
    border-left:1px #FFF solid ;
    float:left;
    color:#FFF;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

header ul {
    width:321px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:url(repeatback.png);
    height:30px;
}
```

requested html:

```
<ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Resume</li>
    <li>Links</li>
    <li>Twitzar</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: centered in what? please post your html markup.

Comment: `text-align:center` won't work if you don't specify width on your `li`'s

Comment: @ptriek thanks , hopefully sticking them in a anchor tag will work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to have your text centered within the list item? You need to specify a width on the element for `text-align: center` to work correctly.

For an example refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUxnK/1

Note, that the css was tweaked slightly to show the centered text.

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Resume</li>
        <li>Links</li>
        <li>Twitzar</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#header ul {
    width:700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 30px;
}

#header li{
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    float:left;
    padding:2px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dffqy/).  In my solution, you do not need a width for each `li`.  Rather, I used `text-align: center` on the container `ul`, made each `li` `display: inline`, and changed the margins and padding so that the borders appear correctly.